# What would be the most efficient design for a ship that is propelled telekinetically

Tags: science-based, science-in-society, aircraft, flying-machines

Suppose you possess a great level of telekinesis capable of molding steel into almost any shape just by concentrating.

And you could use it to both create a ship and propel it at almost any speed you desire.

What would be the most aerodynamic shape for this ship (the design that would result in the least friction, and thus the greatest efficiency) considering there must be enough space for a person inside.

Comment: Don’t ask for “the best” something without some criteria for determining how to rank them.

Comment: efficiency:more work generated with the least amount of resources,in the case of this specifically the most aerodynamic shape possible

Comment: @joaosturza He is not likely to re-open your question unless you edit it and word it better while adding what you said about efficiency.

Comment: @WilliamC is right: this is not a discussion forum. Rather, these comments are review notes for you.

Comment: I'd like to point out that the shapes of ships are *aleady* designed for fuel efficiency, and the idea of finding the most aerodynamic shape has nothing to do with *how* you push it.  “what is the optimal aerodynamic shape for a hull, if you didn't worry about engine ports etc.” is a **real world** pgysics question that might be quickly answered on [physics.se].

Comment: [If I need to be blunt (pun intended)](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=most+efficient+aerodynamic+shape)… I [trivially find](https://www.papertrell.com/apps/preview/The-Handy-Physics-Answer-Book/Handy%20Answer%20book/What-is-the-most-aerodynamic-shape/001137019/content/SC/52caff9682fad14abfa5c2e0_default.html)  the teardrop [and others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nose_cone_design)

Answer (score 1):

Tapered Thin Elliptical Ship. Allows good aerodynamics, and little resistance.

[image: The left. Compared to the normal ellipsoid on the right it is more aerodynamic]

The one on the right.

Comment: could you provide an image?

Comment: That’s not actually the most aerodynamic profile.

Comment: @JDlugosz but unlike other aerodynamic profiles, it offers a lot of space to put things inside.

Comment: The teardrop shape has lots of room.  The most drag-free nose shape attached to a cylinder has more room than what these pictures show.

Comment: @JDlugosz but a teardrop shape has to be turned around to keep that aerodynamics. A tapered ellipsoid can be reversed without turning around.

Comment: Is reversability one of his requirements?  Seriously, look at the profile of a “bullet train”: it has a complex “efficient” shape on *both ends* and that shape is not a simple point.  I can’t remember what it's called, but I'm sure someone interested could find it.